# Which dash should be used to indicate "None", "No Answer", or "Not Applicable"?

Tags: punctuation, symbols, dashes, typography

Consider the following overview of an individual's profile:

> **Name**: John Smith
>   **Age**: 29
>   **Marital status**: Single
>   **Spouse's Name**: -

The dash given as "Spouse's Name" indicates that there is no name, because there is no spouse.  What is the correct character to use for this dash?

Comment: This is not a matter of english language or usage.

Comment: A **lot** of forms will explicitly request that you write something such as **n/a** *(not applicable)* in these situations. But it's certainly not an ELU question anyway.

Comment: Wow.  Okay, everybody, thanks for the slap in the face.  I consider this to be part of English usage, as much as the correct character to hyphenate John's half-sister's last name is part of English usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dash or hyphen is a symbol commonly used in tables to represent absence of information. Depending on context, it is an abbreviation for "missing data", "not applicable", or even "exactly zero".

There is no single correct character (glyph) to use, because there is no prevalent usage or any kind of standard. The symbol used might be a hyphen, an en-dash, or an em-dash.

It is true that a two-em dash indicates where some letters have been left out of a word, and a three-em dash indicates where a word has been entirely left out. But you would be hard pressed to find an example of this in a table.

Therefore, the choice of symbol is left up to you. Simply choose the one which makes your table easiest to read.

Comment: Or you could do the sort of thing that lots of computer systems do: Require the user to enter a spouse name regardless of the marital status specified. :-)